# Unable to hit localhost programmatically - HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: localhost

I have two java apps running locally app1 and app2. I do not have source code for app2, however I can make some config changes and point it to hit a webservice running locally (app1).

I can use the url for the local webservice (on app1) and hit it from a browser (and get results) but app2 directly cannot hit this url. I know app2 is running fine as I can point it to hit one of your test environment urls.

The error I get is this - **Http request failed with response code HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden.**

So I cannot understand - When I can hit the url from a browser why can I not hit it from another app? There have been some recent changes with some **proxy configuration** in our company, but I am not sure if that should affect any url that starts with localhost:8180/..

Because of this I am not able to do any local testing for app1. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what is going on. We were using a proxy for making calls in our HttpClient configuration. Obviously the proxy did not know what the localhost was and so the request failed. In this configuration we have a exclude list that should by-pass the proxy - I added localhost to that list and things have started to work.